# Where are my settings that say use DHCP rather than Static?

Tags: configuration, dhcp, ip-address

I am running Lubuntu 16.10 on a VM, its using DHCP (because that's the default at installation, and i did not do anything special to change it). My host OS is Win10 connected via Wi-Fi / wireless.

Dr Googles says the settings are held in /etc/network/interfaces.

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces =>
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) 
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback
```

, is all i get. Where are my settings that says use dhcp?
I did not see the line

```
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I understand that dhcp in the above line needs to be changed to static (if i want static, which I do), but where is that line to start with?

Answer (score 1):

That's NetworkManager doing its magic.

If you want to use a static address edit `/etc/network/interfaces` as usual and reboot. NetworkManager should then ignore the interfaces defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Use `ip addr show` to see the device names of you network controllers.

Comment: What does "edit `/etc/network/interfaces` as usual" mean? The OP showed us his `interfaces` file, and there's nothing in there about the wireless interface — what should he change?

Comment: They don't have to change anything. The OP was simply wondering where is their network interface specified. Note that it is the _host_ which is connected via Wi-Fi. The Linux _guest_ is connected via a virtual wired Ethernet controller. Since the OP was puzzled that the network interface was not in `/etc/network/interfaces` I assumed that they know what they are doing; by editing `/etc/network/interfaces` as usual I mean insert a stanza beginning with `auto _interfacename_` and continuing with `iface _interfacename_ static` for a fixed IP address and so on and so forth.

Comment: Please show `ifconfig -a`